# Should converted categorical data be standardized/normalized in R for SVM and Logistic Regression?

Tags: r

I have numeric data such as salary, which I have standardized in one script, and normalized in another.
I have categorical data such as city, type. Which I have converted to numeric by setting to a factor, using labels then converting:

```
data$type <- factor(data$type, ordered=FALSE, levels = c("type a","type b","type c","type d", "type e"),labels = c(1,2,3,4,5))
data$type <- as.numeric(as.character(data$type))
```

As some of the factors have many levels (some have 30), is it wise to standardize/normalize these as well for the purpose of using in SVM and logistic regression?

Comment: there are existing questions that address this, for example http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/52915/how-to-deal-with-an-svm-with-categorical-attributes

Comment: This sounds like a question better suited for CrossValidated.

Comment: @JPC Thanks, the question you are referring to was answered but did not talk about if standardizing/normalizing the binary categorical data should be done or not.

Comment: @CJava if it is binary data, I don't see how you are going to normalize it for each observation...

Comment: @JPC Would it be worth creating dummy columns (e.g. is_type_a, is_type_b) with 1 if true, 0 if not?

Comment: @CJava that's what I would do, yes